# Libvlc screen recording

Tags: c++, linux, libvlc

I need to save my screen while program is working in linux. I have tried

```
string out = filepath;
stringstream cmd;

cmd << "cvlc -v screen:// '--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264}:file{dst=" << out <<"} ' &"
system(cmd.str().c_str());
```

This command not works. What should i change in this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem/
Here is working code:

```
cvlc -I 'dummy' screen:// --screen-left=0 --screen-top=0 --screen-width=1280 --screen-height=960 --screen-fps=30 \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v, vb=800, scale=1, acodec=none}:file{mux=ts, dst=your_video_path_to_be_saved}'
```